# What is the best pattern for a hierarchical navigation with 3 entry points in Android?

Tags: android-layout, android, android-tabs, navigation-drawer

I have a hierarchical view structure with 3 entry points, say one section is called "Animals",  another one "Addresses" and a third one "Maps". These 3 sections don't relate to each other.
In each section the content is navigated in a hierarchy, preferably with the title of each view in the action bar as well as an "up" button to move up.

I couldn't find out what's the best way to implement such structure in android.

The options I've found so far:

- Using a navigation drawer. However, google states clearly that you should use the drawer if your app structure is complex, which I believe is not the case for my app. It would have only 3 buttons for the main entry points in it.
- Using a tab bar: This doesn't seem to be supported by Android at all. Or am I wrong on that one? There is no supported way to have a master tab bar and inside of each tab a navigation hierarchy using the action bar. In Android, only the other way around exists: Having A navigation hierarchy and inside one node a tab bar.
- Using action bar buttons for navigation. This one seems odd to me,
- Using a master/detail flow. This would have the advantage that on a tablet, the 3 main entry points would be always accessible. However, I'm not sure if I can use the action bar navigation with up button along with it? Also, I think it's not made for main navigation, but rather for content exploration.

It seems to me that the navigation drawer wins. But then, as stated above, it should only be used for complex navigation.

So my questions are:

Are there more options for this particular app structure?

What do you think is the best pattern to implement it? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact here is only question NavigationDrawer or Tabs navigation.

NavigationDrawer is trending now, and almost all apps try to implement it. You are right, Google recommends use for apps with complex navigation, however in their own apps you could see exception for this rule (for example Music app).

On other hand, from what you described Tabs navigation is also a good choice for you. From my experience one app which is really great implements Tabs navigation is Twitter app.

My advise is to use Tabs navigation (based on what you have described), however using NavigationDrawer is also is not the wrong choice. In general NV is more flexible solution, because you always could change numbers of entry points.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to implement Navigation Drawer in such cases. Some good reasons behind the decision can be :

1. More and more apps are using this design pattern. It is slick, clean and fast.
2. Since you mentioned that each section is accompanied by a content hierarchy so NV comes to the           rescue as you can use fragments and provide deep linking within the content. Most of the other implementations do not support this feature.  [image: provides the ability to access any top level content from anywhere from the app no matter how deep level you're in]
3. The design is scalable. You can easily add more sections in the drawer and corresponding fragments to the main content. Simply add more items in the drawer list and a new fragment in the clicklistner switch case and you're done.